# Apache doesn't execute script of index.php in root automatically

Tags: php, apache, http

This is strange: my Apache is configured with `DirectoryIndex index.html,index.php` so when I type http://gustavopi-macmini.local/ it searches for `index.php` and loads it ok if there is only html tags in the file.

But if I put some php script in `index.php`, it loads `index.html.en` instead (It Works!). However, if I type http://gustavopi-macmini.local/index.php it loads and executes the script.

Also, if I put an `index.php` file in a subdirectory and type http://gustavopi-macmini.local/somesubdirectory/ it loads and executes `index.php` normally as it should...

Why this strange behavior of "jumping" from a php script in the root occurring?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *order* of the defined 'directory index' files also determine their priority.

In your situation, if both an `index.html` and a `index.php` are present, Apache will pick the `index.html`.

To change this, change the order of the 'directory index' files;

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
```

Read the documentation here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: It doesn't affect the problem, Apache loads the php IF there is not php code inside. I tried anyway, but didn't work.

Comment: Apache loading `index.html.en` is caused by the 'Content Negotiation' module [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html) if you don't need that, you can disable it.

Comment: This module can't be disabled, Apache stop working. However, this morning (after a good coffee) I saw a "," in DirectoryIndex between index.php index.html. Removing it solve the problem. I think this directive were ignore by syntax error so Content Negotiation handle looking for index.html or index.html.en causing the strange situation.

Comment: I had seen the comma and didn't include that in my example, but now see that I forgot to mention that.. sorry! However, glad that you were able to solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Don't put comma (,) between **index.html** and **index.php** and as it is said by "thaJeztah" the order in the directive **DirectoryIndex** is important and it defines the file that will be served if there is the two files index.html and index.php in the requested directory:

If you want to give priority to index.html write this:

**DirectoryIndex index.html index.php**

If you want to give priority to index.php write this:

**DirectoryIndex index.php index.html**