# Apache2 on Ubuntu 14.04 won't load index.php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu-14.04

Using the following posts:

- [Ubuntu 14.04 apache2 configuration problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23460150/ubuntu-14-04-apache2-configuration-problems)
- [.htaccess file not working on Ubuntu 14.04 with apache2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743674/htaccess-file-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-apache2)
- [Apache doesn't execute script of index.php in root automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15626438/apache-doesnt-execute-script-of-index-php-in-root-automatically)

I've changed my `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` file to be the following:

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory
```

And I've created the file `/var/www/html/.htaccess` to be the following:

```
DirectoryIndex Index.php index.php Index.html index.html Index.htm index.htm
```

When I go to my site, the default page is still the (It Works!) index.html file.

How do I configured Apache to give priority to index.php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your DocumentRoot `/var/www/` or `/var/www/html/` (the latter is where you say you have your `.htaccess` file)??

If the `.htaccess` is in `/var/www/html/` than I'm gonna guess you need to update your Apache config to be:

`<Directory /var/www/html/>`